# DataImportHandler can't add/update

Tags: solr, addition, dataimporthandler

I am trying to convince solr to perform a bulk import of a sqlite database. 
I follow the all instruction from Solr-Wiki. 
I configured DataImportHandler to open that database through jdbc successfully and I can start the import  http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import 
but whatever I do, DIH didn't add any document even though it seems index the DB

the result

```
    <str name="command">full-import</str>

<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">**14**</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2012-04-06 01:14:30</str>
<str name="">**Indexing completed**. **Added/Updated: 0 documents**. Deleted 0 documents.</str>
<str name="Committed">2012-04-06 01:14:32</str>
<str name="Optimized">2012-04-06 01:14:32</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
```

I use the emp table in Oracle DB

data-config.xml

```
    <dataConfig>
<dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL" user="scott" password="tiger"/>
<document>
<entity name="emp" query="select EMPNO, ENAME from EMP">
            <field column="EMPNO" name="empno" />
            <field column="ENAME" name="ename" />
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml

```
<field name="empno" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="ename" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

It doesn't seem to index, but not to stored indexed data

Any ideas why this problem happen?

**EDIT 1**
Log show warning message like..

```
    WARNING: Error creating document : SolrInputDocument[{ename=ename(1.0)={SMITH}, empno=empno(1.0)={7369}}]
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: id
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:346)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:293)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:636)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
```

that kind of log followed and

this warning message show up end of the log

```
    2012. 4. 6 오후 12:12:25 org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=*:*,add=[(null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), ... (14 adds)],optimize=} 0 0
```

I thought **missing required field: id** has some relation with the configuration in 
the schema.xml

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

but after delete, I got this message

HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: false in solr.xml ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: QueryElevationComponent requires the schema to have a uniqueKeyField implemented using StrField at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:158) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform

Any advice?

Comment: Check logs to see if DIH throws an error. Else use the verbose output of the DataImportHandler Development Console to see what happens.

Comment: thanks! I got log message but still didn't know how to fix it. Any advice?

Comment: I got an answer. delete <uniqueKey>, <defaultSearchField> in schema.xml and <!-- --> to the searchComponent name=elevator in solrconfig.xml. thx!!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    <entity name="emp" query="select EMPNO, ENAME from EMP">
        <field column="EMPNO" name="id" />
        <field column="ENAME" name="ename" />
```

in data-config.xml and put back:

```
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

in schema.xml and also let the field id.

Or u can simply replace:

```
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

with:

```
    <uniqueKey>epno</uniqueKey>
```

Hope that will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add an autoincrement id with

```
 <dataConfig>
<script><![CDATA[
    id = 1;
    function GenerateId(row) {
        row.put('id', (id ++).toFixed());
        return row;
    }
   ]]></script>
<dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL" user="scott" password="tiger"/>
<document>
<entity name="emp" query="select EMPNO, ENAME from EMP" transformer="script:GenerateId">
        <field column="EMPNO" name="empno" />
        <field column="ENAME" name="ename" />   
        </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```